# Relationship between God's power and God's will

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism

In the Catechism of the Catholic Church, it states that "In God, His will, power, essense, and wisdom are all identical".

Does this statement mean that for everything that God can't do, God doesn't will them also? (Ex not only that God cannot sin, but God is also not willing to commit sin; not only that he cannot create a rock so heavy that he can't lift it, but he is also not willing to create such rock, etc)

I guess the starting point is to divide the stuffs that God can't do into two categories - one category being anything that goes against God's own nature, and the other category being any illogical statements...

would it be true to say that for anything that goes against God's own nature, God does not will them also, but in the case of illogical statements that God is unable to perform, God neither wills them nor doesn't will them because illogical statements are nonsensical?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! If you haven't already done so, please browse our [help centre](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and check out [how we are different to other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites?s=1|1.9018) as coming to grips with the site guidelines is not straightforward, but it can prevent unnecessary frustration if you do so.

Comment: *for everything that God can't do* is, in Christianity, a  null set.  Matthew 19:26 for a scriptural reference.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when these sort of statements are made it is due to the infinity of God. The concept works like this.  **As God has no boundaries he has no parts or pieces of personality.** He is only one boundless being, no more loving then just, no more holy then wise but infinite in all his qualities. In this sense you could say all his properties are identical in that all his properties are acting in a perfect unbounded and undivided unity.  It's a basic conclusion of assuming the infinitude of God and is at the same time inserting that God is incomprehensible by the finite due to this quality.

Note: Oh about the illogical things, it's a side issue. Maybe we can just say finite logic and it's associated failures are outside God's wisdom and knowledge as they are a result of death, whereas God is infinitely alive.